# Linking python code to FLASK

Tags: python, flask, bioinformatics

How does one link a standalone python code to use in flask.

example.

```
import sys

# By design, the patterns come in one per line piped in from STDIN

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
line = line.strip()
# 1) Split the pattern into clauses. 
# 2) Translate each clause into regex syntax
# 3) reassemble the full regex pattern
clauses = line.split("-")
regex_clause_array = []
for clause in clauses:
    # re_clause: the incremental build-up of the clause into regex syntax
    re_clause=None
    # Convert the prosite negation into a regex inverted character class
    if clause.startswith("{"):
        neg_pieces = clause.split("}")
        # neg_pieces[0][1:] is the character set for the negation
        # neg_pieces[1] is the optional quantification
        re_clause = "[^%s]%s" % (neg_pieces[0][1:], neg_pieces[1])
    else:
        re_clause = clause
    # change the quantification parenthesis into regex curly-braces
    re_clause = re_clause.replace(")","}")
    re_clause = re_clause.replace("(","{")
    # change wildcards from 'x' to '.'
    re_clause = re_clause.replace("x",".")
    # save the regex-syntax clause to the regex clause array
    regex_clause_array.append(re_clause)
# add the leading and trailing slashes and concatenate all regex clauses
# together to form the full regex pattern
print ("/%s/" % ("".join(regex_clause_array)))
```

The code above works on its own which it takes a sequence for example                         P-x(2)-G-E-S-G(2)-[AS] and convert into python regex P.{2}GESG{2}[AS].

What I cant figure out is that I am trying to use flask to link this into a webtool. What I have for now is a simple webpage that has a text box and a submit button but fail to link the above code to the routing app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the code in different python file and name it. Now ,You can use the python file as a module. Put the code in a function. You can import the python file in flask.

```
 from filename import function
```

You can use it inside views like

```
@app.route('/link' , methods = ['POST'])
def view_function():
     call = function()
```

Now in submit button you can do something like this:

```
<form action="/link" method = 'post'>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: In order for this to work, the file you `import` has to follow a few conventions, the most important of which is having the main functionality in a function you can import, and using `if __name__ == '__main__':` to avoid running that function if imported.